# store kit transaction error: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" on ios 7 device

Tags: ios, iphone, transactions, ios7, app-store-connect

On product request I am getting all the products. I am also getting the product buy alert in below ios 7 devices but not for the ios 7 and above.

For ios 7 and above I am getting an error as:
**Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store**

I am running app on the device itself and not on the simulator.
I have gone through other SO as well but unable to rectify my problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue. Here is similar question [I am getting error while requesting products from App Store for IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255654/i-am-getting-error-while-requesting-products-from-app-store-for-iap)

Try doing this:
1)You have to test on device
2)Go to setting -> iTunes & App Store -> and log out of your account.
Remove app from device and clean all data.
Make sure you have done all necessary steps for in-App purchase testing. Here is apple
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html)
Run on device and test it.

Comment: Apple documentation link is broken. Found this - not sure original intention - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: Didn’t work for me. Had exactly the same message as before: Transaction error: cannot connect to iTunes Store

Answer (score 1):

If you having similar issue, please, check that you do not have expired contracts in itunesconnect.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was requesting SKProducts and got this error. Interesting investigation. After I set the Date & Time for a day earlier the SKProducts come as they have to.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have already followed what Kostiantyn's answer and this still happens on your device, try to restart it.

It works for me. I am not sure what is the reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and after researching this for some time, I found the solution

> **Go to: Settings -> iTunes & App Store -> Sandbox Account (Check logged in account here)**

In my case I was using the wrong email here that's why I was getting **Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store**

Hope that saves you some time.