# App cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have made an app with In-App purchases by following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) Ray Wenderlich tutorial. I get an error when trying to request the products for the In-App purchases. This is the error message I get:

```
2013-12-01 18:17:46.030 In App Rage 2[1634:a0b] Error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2   "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x996f5a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to   iTunes Store}
```

from this method:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I have searched the web but haven't found what's wrong. What could be wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Store Kit "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a similar question on another stack overflow post:

[I am getting error while requesting products from App Store for IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255654/i-am-getting-error-while-requesting-products-from-app-store-for-iap)

It says that apple blocked testing in app purchases in the simulator.

Does that help?

Comment: It did help, I tried it in the simulator first but in my real device it works fine. Thank you!