# Can In App Purchase be tested using the iOS 8 Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, storekit

It seems to work until the point where I get an alert with the message: You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded.

Comment: Actually no it does not work as of now with Xcode 6.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18922133/129202

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot about it, and all I understood form this answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102236/2382237

that the only one way to test it on ios8  - launch app on the real device.